# Delete all apps from iTunes that aren't on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automated/Simple Deletion of Apps from iTunes Library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38053/automated-simple-deletion-of-apps-from-itunes-library)

Is there a way to auto-delete apps from iTunes that aren't on my iPhone? I have about 200 of them and don't want to do it manually.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: I think this has been covered before

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38053/automated-simple-deletion-of-apps-from-itunes-library

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the apps in iTunes.
Sync your iPhone and allow the sync of purchased apps to your iTunes library.

Actually, [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/38180/11600) already covers this.